# What is an instance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance

I have this model. and my freind told me that . I should only have one **INSTANCE** on unique/confno . .

Where is the instance here?

```
class Confbridge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :confbridge_schedules, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :confno, uniqueness: true, :allow_nil => true, :allow_blank => true

 :confno => confno, :circle => cid, :confbridge_id => id )

end
```

**and how can i easily understance instance?**

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance usually represents one row in your database table, but more generally it has a very specific meaning relating to your class.

Classes and instances are Object Oriented Programming concepts, but can be present in other contexts too.

Even in the real world...
Lets pretend you have a class called 'Car'

An instance would be the specific car that you have parked in your garage right now. Another instance would be your neighbour's car.

In a database context, if your class was called 'EmployeeRecord' then an instance of that would be the record that has your name and employee-number on it, as opposed to the one for your boss.

But in your case, in Rails:
You have a class called `Confbridge`. If you create a new one of these using eg `conf = Confbridge.new` then what you have in the variable `conf` is an instance of class `Confbridge`

To specifically look at the code you've showed - you don't have an instance in that code. What you have shown above is the code that makes up the `Confbridge` class - from that you can make instances that will have the properties you defined when writing the class (eg each of your instances will validate that `confno` is unique if you call `conf.save`)

Comment: Hi @Taryn East . . Can I ask what is the purpose of .rake eg(mon_batch_scripts.rake) What is the difference between .rake and .rb file?

Comment: Nice work but I had to downvote because it doesn't really explain what it is

Comment: @RichPeck the OP was satisfied... also I answered what was actually asked - to understand the idea of what an instance is, and point out where the instance was in the code provided.

Comment: No problem, I would have downvoted and not mentioned anything; I just wanted to put it out there that I was the one who downvoted that's all

Answer (score 4):

To be short, instance is an object of a certain class. In your example `Confbridge` is a model class. All of the following are instances of this class:

```
Confbridge.new
Confbridge.first
Confbridge.find(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

An *instance* comes from [Object Orientated Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (which Ruby is a proponent of)...

[image]

OOP basically replaces *variables* with *objects* (although they're the same thing).

The difference between the two is that an *object* is stored either as a "class" or a "function", with both *attributes* and *functions*/*methods* appended to it.

In short, objects can be *manipulated* in the application whilst variables are static.

---

Games use OOP because it allows you to invoke a series of objects into the environment and interact with them.

For example, with [Mario](http://superprofundo.com/2010/12/09/object-oriented-programming-in-a-nutshell/), `Mario` will be an object, a `Koopa` can be an object etc.

When you move, you're editing `Mario`'s "position" (`x`/`y`) in the environment, which can also mean that if the coords intersect with another object, Mario dies...

```
def keypress
   @mario.move x,y
end

class Mario
   def move x,y 
     ##updates environment
     ##checks if collision
   end
end
```

The interactivity between these objects is what allows games to seem like they retain their state (each enemy is an object with different characteristics).

Thus, when you think about `Rails`, you must appreciate that *everything* you do is object-orientated. All your variables etc should be objects. Models are responsible for building these objects with certain attributes/methods etc:

```
#app/models/car.rb
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   def blow_up!
      self.destroy
   end
end

@car = Car.find params[:id] #-> invokes an instance of the Car object, populating with data from the db
@car.blow_up! #-> invoking the "blow_up!" instance method.
```

Thus to describe the *instance* of an object, you're talking about a class which has been initialized & populated with data from your DB.

In your case, the instance occurs in your `Controller`, when you invoke the class with one of the [class methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/):

```
@confbridge = Confbridge.find(1) #-> creates an instance
@confbridge.destroy              #-> performs action on instance
```